# Augmented reality on an image using Vuforia SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I try to create an AR application using unity and vuforia sdk. There are some examples about marker based AR application. But they use ARCamera( it uses embedded camera on a laptop or mobile device).

I have an AR glass(it attaches to pc via usb cable). How can I detect and track marker on an image(taken from AR glass) with vuforia sdk?